# Multi domain support on a single ASP .NET Core MVC application code base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to find an elegant way to support multiple domains on a single ASP.NET Core MVC application.

Example:

- [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com)
- [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)
- [www.domain1.de](http://www.domain1.de)
- [www.domain1.it](http://www.domain1.it)

Basically all the domains should point to the same code base, the design is the same  across the websites, however it should display different data/images, the content is domain dependent.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.  Its hard to know as you have limited description.  If you simply wish to have multiple domains going to the app then its more of DNS settings.  Provide further details.

Comment: are those domains will send the end-user to the same website ? 
if yes then the answer you are looking for is "yes" since it has nothing to do with the application its DNS redirect

Comment: @AliK thanks for your reply. Sorry for not being very clear. Have just updated the description. Let me know if I still have to provide any more details.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada Thanks for your reply. Basically it's the same website but different domains. However depending on the domain, there will be some differences like the language, images etc.

Comment: Yes , you can do that

Comment: Different data? So do you want it to be the same application or not? @Bea

Comment: @SpicyCatGames it should look the same, should have the same design but the data from the database/images is different on each domain. It might sounds weird but this is the requirement.

Comment: @Bea So same code but not same instance of application/ different files for each?

Comment: Anything is possible with enough work. Usually asp.net doesn't care what the `Host:` header is. So you want something like `wwwroot/[domain]/images/....` static files? Some kind of EF Core tenant query filter? Be specific.

Comment: @SpicyCatGames  Somehow, I have to set up a configuration for each domain, the images, the content(I mean the data from database) is loaded based on the domain, from the same database. The frontend side should be the same.
Previously these sites were implemented in .Net Framework 4 and there was a domain config file which was holding the domain details and was wondering how should I do this in .Net Core, if there is a more elegant way than the old one.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman 
The images, the content(I mean the data from database) is loaded based on the domain, from the same database. The frontend side should be the same. 
Previously these sites were implemented in .Net Framework 4 and there was a domain config file which was holding the domain details and was wondering how should I do this in .Net Core, if there is a more elegant way than the old one

Answer (score 0):

After some clarification, OP is asking for same design but different data from backend for each domain. This cannot be done with MVC.

And different data means different application, I'm assuming. So this isn't possible with WebAPI either. All you want is multiple frontends with same design, but different domains and different backend. You're gonna need multiple applications.

Comment: The frontend should be the same, indeed, and the content(I mean the data fetched from database) should be dependent on the domain.
Previously these sites were implemented in .Net Framework 4 and there was a domain config file which was holding the domain details and was wondering how should I do this in .Net Core, if there is a more elegant way than the old one.

Comment: Ok I have thought of a solution but one last question before I write that answer. Are you gonna use entity framework core? @Bea

Comment: We won't use it atm, maybe in the future.

Comment: @Bea so you're using raw SQL? and the queries remain the same for each database?

Comment: @Bea Could you not just have sections in your appsettings.json for each of the domain, and when the app runs, pass in the domain before the connection string key to get the appropriate connection string from configuration?